# Cardano dapp user authentication based on the wallet address

Tags: wallet, address, decentralized-applications, api, security

What are the best options to add user-authentication system based on the wallet address for my website? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few ways to do this- one way I've seen is to request a very specific (small) amount of ADA from that wallet, then send it back (minus TX fees).

Alternatively, you may ask the wallet holder to sign a message with their private key, as specified by [CIP-8](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip8/)